# Lightweight charts issue with crosshair when page is zoomed

Tags: javascript, charts, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

Major issue with TradingView Lightweight Charts 3.8.0:

When I set a different zoom level for body inside the script tag such as:

```
document.body.style.zoom = String(80)+"%";
```

The mouse pointer is always way off the crosshair to the left and top.

What can be done to fix this and bring the crosshair back to the mouse pointer's position when the page is zoomed out?

Here is a code sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/yLpckz0r/

[image]

Comment: This isn't something that can be easily fixed. I would recommend adjusting the `fontSize` value in the layoutOptions if you want to shrink the size of some of the chart components. https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/LayoutOptions#fontsize

Comment: Other components of the site need to be shrinked to 80% so the chart is affected.